# Apache vhost config with puppet and capistrano

Tags: apache2, capistrano, puppet

I am trying to deploy a webserver with puppet, and then I would use capistrano to deploy the code.

My `site.pp` file looks like this:

```
file { ['/var/www/vhost', '/var/www/vhost/current']:
  ensure  => directory,
  replace => false,
}

class { 'apache': }

apache::vhost { 'vhost.site.com':
  port    => '80',
  docroot => '/var/www/vhost/current',
}
```

Problem is, when I deploy with Capistrano, it cannot create the links to the current folder, because it's already there (as a directory).

Can anyone tell me how to set it up so I just point the docroot to the folder, but not actually creating the directory?

I was thinking of a solution where I place the apache2 vhost config file and restart apache2 via puppet... but I don't think that's the right way to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to create a symlink instead of a directory?

Comment: Capistrano creates a symlink called current, which you are supposed to point your docroot to... Problem is that the Apache module will remove the symlink and create a directory, and then Capistrano cannot create the symlink